Application requires default proxy to be set in code instead of taking it from system network proxy
I'm working with a REST service built on .NET Framework 4.8 and have configured a system-level proxy to ensure all external calls route through it. However, the application isn't recognizing this proxy setting, also setting it in the web.config file didn't yield any results either.
Finally specifying the default proxy in the Global.asax file worked.
Does anyone know why the application might not be picking up the proxy settings from the network or web.config? I believe all traffic should ideally go through proxy if it is set at system level.
  WebProxy webProxy = new WebProxy(squidProxyUrl, squidProxyPort)
  {
         BypassList = squidBypassList
  };
  WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = webProxy;

